# unittest example from the docs not working for dynamic list

Tags: python, python-unittest

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#organizing-test-code) this example

```
import unittest


class WidgetTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.widget = Widget('The widget')

    def tearDown(self):
        self.widget.dispose()


def suite():
    suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    suite.addTest(WidgetTestCase('test_default_widget_size'))
    suite.addTest(WidgetTestCase('test_widget_resize'))
    return suite


if __name__ == '__main__':
    runner = unittest.TextTestRunner()
    runner.run(suite())
```

does not show any error by

```
pytest -vv --log-level=INFO mytest.py
```

but it also collects 0 items.

How would I correctly use this way to dynamically generate a list of verbose test results to later have them in the report?

Comment: What tests were you expecting it to find? There's only setup and teardown. Look at the names you're passing when you instantiate the test case - you need to use the example _with those methods in_.

Comment: yes it's obvious that something is missing. I wonder how the widget would have to look like to actually make it work and why the docs example hands over some string which is never read by the class ?

Comment: The string _is_ used, it's the `methodName`. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase. And you could implement Widget by getting the tests to pass - that's how test-first programming works.

Comment: @user3732793 If you execute your code with the command `python my_test.py` you obtain the error `no such test method in <class '__main__.WidgetTestCase'>: test_default_widget_size`, this because you have added the method `test_default_widget_size()` to the suite, but you don't have defined the method `test_default_widget_size()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still not sure what the documentation wanted to schow with the undocumented Widget test.

However if someone comes by the question to dynamically generate a list of test results there is no unittest solution.

The only solution I found is to compile at runtime the list of methods to be tested.

```
import unittest

string_class = "class IterationTestCase(unittest.TestCase):"

testnames = ["test_one","test_two"]
string_tests = ""

for testname in testnames:
    string_one = f"""
        def {testname}(self):
            print(self._testMethodName)
            self.assertTrue(True)
    """
    string_tests = string_tests + string_one

string_tests = string_tests + "\n"
string_unittest = "unittest.main()"
string_unittest = """
unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2)
unittest.main()
"""

string_test = string_class + string_tests + string_unittest
compiled_code = compile(string_test, "<string>", "exec")
exec(compiled_code)
```

Output

```
OK
test_one
test_two
```

not sure if I finally will use it.